# Minimizing the toolbar in MacVim on OSX Lion

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion, macvim

In previous versions of OS X it was possible to minimize the top toolbar of most applications due to a small button in the top right of the window. In Lion however it seems that this has been replaced with the fullscreen toggle. The two versions are shown below

[image: MacVim open in OSX Lion]

[image: MacVim open in OSX Snow Leopard]

Is it possible to have this toolbar default to minimized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Bathz said, you can do it with `:set`, or you can create a `.gvimrc` file at your system root (`~/`), and add settings for your GVim (MacVim in Mac), below is a sample:

```
set guioptions-=T         " Remove toolbar
set guioptions-=r         " Remove right scrollbar
set lines=60 columns=100  " UI size
set guifont=Monaco:h12    " font size
```

Answer (score 3):

I cannot answer you specifically about OSX Lion, but GUI vims have the `guioptions` var to enable/disable some parts of the interface. `:set guioptions-=T` (command mode) will hide the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Only for your info, you can control click the green button (top left of the window) and in the menu you can hide toolbar.This work in almost all windows in Mountain Lion (I don't know if work also in Lion).